# How to add a property to a model which will be calculated based on input?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```py
class TransactionHistory(models.Model):
    from_account = models.ForeignKey(
        'Account',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='from_account'
    )
    to_account = models.ForeignKey(
        'Account',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='to_account'
    )

    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    
    @property
    def way(self):
        # Here I need to access a list of user's accounts
        # (request.user.accounts) to mark the transaction
        # as going out or in.
        return
```

```py
def get_own_transaction_history(me_user):
    my_accounts = me_user.accounts.all()

    # TODO: mark transactions with way as in and out
    own_transactions = TransactionHistory.objects.filter(
        Q(from_account__in=my_accounts) |
        Q(to_account__in=my_accounts)
    )
    return own_transactions
```

I want to add a "way" property for the model so when I return the queryset via serializer, the user could understand if the transaction is for going out from his account or in. But if I just add property, it can not be calculated with me_user user in mind, AFAIK the property can only access the local model fields like "from_account" or "to_account".

Comment: You need to add this property to the objects in the `own_transactions` queryset? An annotation might be your best bet, how complex is the `way` property?

Comment: I will need to check if the from_account is in my_accounts, if so mark as "out" otherwise mark as "in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work as an annotation using [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/), using `__in` in the `When` expressions may give a bit of trouble though. The objects returned by this queryset will have an attribute `way` added to them by the annotation

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When


def get_own_transaction_history(me_user):
    my_accounts = me_user.accounts.all()
    return TransactionHistory.objects.filter(
        Q(from_account__in=my_accounts) |
        Q(to_account__in=my_accounts)
    ).annotate(
        way=Case(
            When(from_account__in=my_accounts, then=Value('out')),
            When(to_account__in=my_accounts, then=Value('in')),
            output_field=CharField(),
        )
    )
```